# How to get max value in a dictionary with value as lits?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get the max value out of my dictionary which has a list as the value and return the key and the value.

My dictionary looks like this:

```
d = {'Miami': [1, 12, 7, 12], 'New York': [21, 12, 1, 8]}
```

And I want to get the answer:

```
New York 21
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The items in the lists are all strings? So, its `'12'` and not `12`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the maximum value in the dictionary, and then find the maximum of its key:

```
d = {'Miami': [1, 12, 7, 12], 'New York': [21, 12, 1, 8]}
m = max(d, key=lambda x:max(d[x]))
print(f'{m} {max(d[m])}')
```

Output:

```
New York 21
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is correct formated:

```
d = {'Miami': [1, 12, 7, 12], 'New York': [21, 12, 17, 8]}

def getmaxvalues(citys):
    for city in citys:
        print("The biggest value in {0} is {1}".format(city, max(citys[city])))

def overallmax(citys):
    overallmax = max(citys, key=max)
    print("{0} {1}".format(overallmax, max(citys[overallmax])))

getmaxvalues(d)
overallmax(d)
```

-> The biggest value in Miami is 12
-> The biggest value in New York is 21

-> New York 21

else you have to remove `‘` and `'` first please confirm.

Comment: That solution doesn't completely solve the problem. OP is not looking for max in each, he's looking to report the single max.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Easy to fix the formatting in the list, to make it integers. But looking for the overall max not in each list.

Answer (score 1):

If `d` contains lists of integers (not strings), you can just use the nativ python `max` function with the `key` argument:

```
>>> d = {'Miami': [1, 12, 3], 'New York': [21, 3, 4]}
>>> max(d.items(), key=lambda x: max(x[1]))
('New York', [21, 3, 4])
```

The `key` keyword controls which values are compared. Here the key is a `lambda` object, which returns here the maximum value of the second entry of the argument. The argument that is put in are all items of the dictionary (key-value pairs).

If you need to work with string lists, you have to convert the strings to numbers first. This can be done easily:

```
>>> d = {'Miami': ['1', '12', '3'], 'New York': ['21', '3', '4']}
>>> max(d.items(), key=lambda x: max(float(i) for i in x[1]))
('New York', ['21', '3', '4'])
```

The last step is to print the result nicely. But I have good faith that you will be able to figure that out yourself.